# Ordenação Linq Dinâmico utilizando System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, classificação

Estou tentando ordenar uma lista utilizando a biblioteca `System.Linq.Dynamic`, segue o trecho do código:

```
list = db.TABELA.Where(consulta.Colum + ".Contains(@0) ",     
consulta.filtro).OrderBy("@0 ", "codigo").Take(10).ToList();
```

porém o resultado, neste caso, é sempre o mesmo, já tentei de algumas formas (`DESC, ASC`), ele vem a ordenação original do banco. estou tentando ordenar em ordem decrescente e não consigo. Alguém pode me ajudar? Grato desde já!

Comment: Só com isso é difícil ajudar. Precisa de contexto. De uma maneira geral isso n]ao é para funcionar mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

O `OrderBy` na sua consulta está gerando uma ordenação da palavra **codigo** e não do campo **`codigo`** como está na sua expressão `Linq Dynamic` (`OrderBy("@0 ", "codigo")`), na SQL abaixo isso fica bem claro:

```
SELECT
    [Project1].*    
    FROM ( SELECT
        N'Codigo' AS [C1],        
        FROM [dbo].[TABELA] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

Então, para para funcionar corretamente, deveria ser:

```
OrderBy("Codigo ASC")
```

Um dica de muita utilidade é verificar pelo [Log do Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn479056.aspx) o que está sendo gerado:

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
{
     db.Database.Log = c => Console.WriteLine(c);
     //...
}
```

Nesse caso gera direto no console quais `SQL` foram geradas e com isso você debuga sabendo o porque das inconsistências.